# Perl regex read line and search or compare each element in the array or hash

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, hash

In my Perl code I am able to compare string  and print if my file line contain string .

```
while (my $line = <$input_fh>) {
  chomp $line;

  if ($line =~ /<red>/) {
    $start_writing = 1;
    next;
  }
}
```

I wonder if this it is possible to compare all the colors in an array, for example if I have an array like:

```
my @colors qw(<red> <blue> <green> <yellow>);
```

can I search each element of the array and comapre with $line =~. So the code should look for either color red, blue, green, or yellow and print if any of this color exists in the $line.

Comment: Well, you can do alternatives: `if ($line =~ /<red>|<blue>|<green>|<yellow>/)`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few approaches. One is to just build a regular expression with a lot of alternations:

```perl
my @colors = qw(<red> <blue> <green> <yellow>);
# Escape any RE metacharacters in the words.
my $re = join("|", map(quotemeta, @colors));

while (my $line = <$input_fh>) {
  chomp $line;

  if ($line =~ /$re/) {
    $start_writing = 1;
    next;
  }
}
```

My favorite though, if you're just looking for a bunch of literal strings, is to use the [`Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS) module (Install through your OS package manager  or a CPAN client) to do it [really efficiently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm):

```perl
use Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS;

my @colors = qw(<red> <blue> <green> <yellow>);
my $searcher = Algorithm::AhoCorasick::XS->new(\@colors);

while (my $line = <$input_fh>) {
  chomp $line;

  if ($searcher->first_match($line)) {
    $start_writing = 1;
    next;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read each color and look into each line of file and print it if any color matches in the line:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @colors = qw(<red> <blue> <green> <yellow>);

my $file = 'sample.txt';

open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't open file $file: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    foreach my $color (@colors) {
        $color =~ s/[<>]//g;    # Remove angle brackets from color
        if ($line =~ /\b$color\b/i) {
            print "$line\n";
            last;   # Once a color is found in the line, move on to the next line
        }
    }
}
close $fh;
```

Output:

```
Roses are red, violets are blue.
The grass is green, the sun is shining.
The banana is yellow.
```

sample.txt

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Roses are red, violets are blue.
The grass is green, the sun is shining.
The banana is yellow.
There are no colors in this line.
```